# Play sound in the WebView provided by vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, webview, html5-audio

I want to develop a plug-in to play local sound.So I make a demo for test with `audio`
:

```html
<audio src="vscode-resource:/Users/asure/Documents/Projects/test/EffectMove.mp3" controls>
```

`/Users/asure/Documents/Projects/test` it's the directory where I tested it.I also tested after adding it to `localResourceRoots`.Below was what I get.

[image: player]
It seems that sound didn't load correctly while no errors can be found in console window.I was confused whether `vscode` disable audio related content in `webview` or something was wrong in my code.
Does anyone know how to play sound in the `webview` provided by `vsocde`

Answer (score 1):

VSCode does not support playing sound with audio tag in WebView.
you can use web audio API instead.

and [there is already an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sukumo28.wav-preview) that plays local sound files with web audio API.

Answer (score 0):

Because vscode does not support audio playback.

> Actually, I just learned that we strip out ffmpeg and other media support from our release builds. This is by-design and something we will not change, but it does mean that many types of media playback will never be supported in webviews inside vscode

source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32540

Answer (score 0):

Vscode v1.71 will support various audio codecs within a `webView`.

See [release notes: ffmpeg support](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_71.md#ffmpeg-codecs-support).

It includes `mp3` suuport and

```
Vorbis
Flac
H.264
VP8
WAV
MP3
Ogg
```